# bash script to zip multiple subfolders in a directory

Tags: bash, gzip, tar

I need to find resprective subfolders with a pattern and gzip each one separately. I have done the first leg but unsure how to zip them

```
$ find . \( -iname 'NE*' -type d \)
./NE1
./NE2
./NE3
```

I tried this but i dont think ive got it right?

```
 find . \( -iname 'NE*' -type d \) -exec tar -czvf NE*.tar.gz --verbose {} \;
```

Comment: Why would you use an asterisk in a filename?

Comment: Btw, you're missing a space before `--verbose`.

Comment: i am searching folders that has an prefix NE

Comment: it does not tar each folder

Comment: Did you mean: `tar -czvf '{}'.tar.gz`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
find . \( -iname 'NE*' -type d \) -exec bash -c 'tar -czvf "$1.tar.gz" --verbose "$1" && rm -rf "$1"' - {} \;
```

Comment: much appreciated. Once the folders are zipped, is there an option to delete the folder once successfully tarred/zipped?

Comment: @nick Answer updated

Comment: thank you @philippe. just what i needed. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Another option (maybe it's more readable) is using `xargs`:

```
find . -iname 'NE*' -type d | xargs -I subdir -- tar -cvzf subdir.tar.gz subdir
```